# XCUITest is sending my app to the background when running tests through BrowserStack and Appium

Tags: automation, appium-ios, xcuitest

I have an app that I have automated in IntelliJ to connect to BrowserStack and run a test suite.

It runs on both Android and iOS devices. Using BrowserStack, which I believe uses Appium 2.1, works fine when running on an Android device which uses the UIAutomator framework and the test run as expected. However when running the same test for iOS, using the XCUITest framework it closes the app to the background throughout the test run (I have proven this by bringing the app back from the background using the activateApp command) but i can't figure out why it is doing this

Running on BrowserStacks AppLive system and local devices and manually running the tests does have the issue and appears to only happen when using the XCUITest framework.

Has anyone come across this and knows why it does it or how to resolve it?

I expect the test to run without putting the app to the background.

EDIT
Latest run crash log snippet

```html
"vmRegionInfo" : "0x20 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 68719476704\n      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT\/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL\n      UNUSED SPACE AT START\n--->  \n      commpage (reserved)     1000000000-7000000000 [384.0G] ---\/--- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)",
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000020","rawCodes":[1,32],"type":"EXC_BAD_ACCESS","signal":"SIGSEGV","subtype":"KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":11,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Segmentation fault: 11","byProc":"exc handler","byPid":851},
  "vmregioninfo" : "0x20 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 68719476704\n      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT\/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL\n      UNUSED SPACE AT START\n--->  \n      commpage (reserved)     1000000000-7000000000 [384.0G] ---\/--- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)",
  "faultingThread" : 0,
```

Comment: Please confirm if you are using iOS 17, if so, please only use these devices:
"iPhone 12", "iPhone 13", "iPhone 15 Pro", "iPhone 15 Pro Max", "iPhone 15 Plus", "iPhone 12 Pro"

Comment: It runs on an IPad Pro 12.9 2022 running OS 16.1. I'll update the original post with a snippet from the lastest run that has a crash log

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter what device or iOS I am running on, it always gets sent to the background.

Comment: Is this between tests or during an individual test? Does this occur locally?

Comment: This occurs whether i run locally as well. I can force the app to return from the back ground but then it fails later in the test as it again gets sent to the background.